# amazon athena create request with partitions

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I create a table with partitions as follow : first by year, month, and day.

Question : I hope get data of 12/2017 and 03/2018, how I can do this? 
What I think do :

```
where (year='2017' and month='12') and ( year ='2018' and month='03')
```

Is it correct? I will not have a confusion so Amazon Athena get data of:

```
12/2017 and 03/2018 and 03/2017 and 12/2018
```

because of the *and* operator ?

PS: I can't test, I have only free account.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I tried in a mini set of data and I found that Amazon Athena take into account the parenthesis.

My test is as follow :
 The DDl of table as générated :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `manyands`(
  `years` int COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `months` int COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `days` int COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mybucket/'
```

My set of data test:
[image]

My tests:

1- `SELECT * FROM "atlasdatabase"."manyands" where month='1';`
I got in CSV format :

```
"years","months","days","year","month"
"2017","1","21","2017","1"
"2018","1","81","2018","1"
```

2- `SELECT * FROM "atlasdatabase"."manyands" where month='1' and year='2017';`

```
"years","months","days","year","month"
"2017","1","21","2017","1"
```

3- `SELECT * FROM "atlasdatabase"."manyands" where (month='1'  and year='2018') and (month='3'  and year='2017') ;`

```
empty (Zéro enregistrements renvoyés)
```

4- `SELECT * FROM "atlasdatabase"."manyands" where (month='1'  and year='2018') or (month='3' ) ;`

```
"years","months","days","year","month"
"2018","1","81","2018","1"
"2017","3","73","2017","3"
"2018","3","73","2018","3"
```

Conclusion : add **OR** operator between many instances of the partitions.